# Need T-SQL help on looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a ticketing database for which I'm writing a stored Procedure to alert each member of my team if they have any open tickets.

I have the select query to find the open tickets for the day. I have to group the tickets by user name and send an email to each individual. (For example, if I have 3 tickets open in my queue I would like to build a table and send 3 rows to me instead of three emails.)

Please guide me what are the functions/keywords I should be looking into in order to loop through each member of the team. I was looking into While loop but couldn't see how it will be helpful to me.

My idea so far is to create a table variable to populate necessary data.

In a Loop,

```
Select blah blah WHERE user = @user
```

TSQL - Build a HTML table Send email to `@user`

I'm stuck how to loop through each user! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Most loops are usually done through `cursor`s or `while` loops. Take a look at the documentation for the two methods. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms178642.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange Yes I did. With cursor I can select all the open tickets for the daya and send email to corresponding folks. But can i group the tickets together based on assignee to send a single email instead of multiple ones if he have multiple tickets on his queue? If we can do that by cursor let me know. I'll investigate further on that. Thanks!

Comment: Sure you can do that easily enough. You want to send a single to UserX who has 3 open tickets and the contents will have details about all their open tickets right? Each iteration through your cursor you are running a query to get the details for that person right? This seems pretty straight forward from here. What part(s) are you having trouble with?

Comment: @SeanLange I am able to send email , one for each row in the table but I'm having trouble to send email to a user about all their open tickets. In my cursor, I have a simple select statement to loop through and send email. I'm not sure how to modify that to get what I'm expecting!

Comment: I don't either because I can't see your screen or read your mind. You haven't shared what you are doing now, what your table schema is like, any sample data or explanation of what you want.

Comment: I think I just got what you're telling @SeanLange. Let me try and get back! Thanks Much!

Comment: @Ramya please check my answer . The output will we username with tickets in tickets table now you need to just html part t make it pretty and formatted as per your need . The output is user A  has ticket t1 and t2 . I added sample input in temp tables please have a look I hope this is what you want .

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your guidance! I was able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @user as table (username varchar(10)  , email varchar (20))
declare @ticket as table (username varchar(10)  , ticketnumber varchar (20))
insert into @user values('A','a.com')
insert into @user values('b','b.com')

insert into @ticket values('A','t1')
insert into @ticket values('A','t2')
insert into @ticket values('b','t3')

 declare @ticketNumber as varchar(100) 
 declare @userName as varchar(100)
 declare @user_cursor cursor
 declare @inner_cursor cursor
 declare @fetch_user_cursor int
 declare @fetch_inner_cursor int

 declare user_cursor cursor static local for 
 SELECT 
       username
  FROM @user

  /*loop through top level cursor*/
  open user_cursor
  fetch next from user_cursor into @userName
  select @fetch_user_cursor = @@FETCH_STATUS

  while @fetch_user_cursor = 0
  begin
    print @userName

     /*loop through second level cursor*/
     set @inner_cursor  = cursor static local for 
     select ticketnumber from @ticket where username = @userName


     open @inner_cursor
     fetch next from @inner_cursor into @ticketNumber
     set @fetch_inner_cursor = @@FETCH_STATUS
     while @fetch_inner_cursor = 0
     begin

      print @ticketNumber

      fetch next from @inner_cursor into @ticketNumber
      set @fetch_inner_cursor = @@FETCH_STATUS
     end
     close @inner_cursor
     deallocate @inner_cursor

     fetch next from user_cursor into @userName
     set @fetch_user_cursor = @@FETCH_STATUS


  end
```

Comment: Inseted of print statement you can create a html structure which you need in email . I posted a minimal answer required for your question

Comment: Let me try your solution. Thanks for your quick help!

Comment: @Ramya  you are welcome I hope you will able to solve your issue and accept my answer

Comment: This works but I would avoid the second cursor and create a set based query for the contents. Also, you can improve the cursor by defining as forward_only. Regardless this captures the idea.